# Django - Filter URL in texts

Tags: python, django, web, security

I would like to know if someone here could help me out finding a way to "filter" URLs inside block of texts, comments for example. I wish to be able to "Block" the submitting of such comments on my website.

So for example, if someone would type `blablabla http://bla.com`, the application would deny the user from submitting its entry. I was able to make a very "homemade" script which looked inside the text to find stuff like `www.` , `.com`, `http` etc. However it doesn't feel very solid at all.

Thanks !

Comment: The implementation depends on the situation you want to use it in. You can validate the data on client side or server side, using regex. Really easy. Try something, tell us if you face any problem.

Comment: Beautiful Soup makes it super-easy to parse HTML: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
simple_url_re = re.compile(r'^(https?)?://\[?\w', re.IGNORECASE)
simple_url_2_re = re.compile(r'^www\.|^(?!http)\w[^@]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org)$', re.IGNORECASE)

if simple_url_re.match(text) or simple_url_2_re.match(text):
    raise ValidationError
```

you can use django's [urlize](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/html.py) for ideas

Comment: Hi there, your script seems to work fine with 'http' and 'www', but doesn't work if I try it with just 'stackoverflow.com' for example. Thanks

Comment: modify the regex to fit your needs